# Como remover essa sombra que aparece quando chega no "fim" da tela?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como que remove essa sombra utilizando o Android Studio? Ela aparece quando termina a rolagem da página.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No xml, na declaração da View, adicione `android:overScrollMode="never"`.

O mesmo pode ser feito no java usando:

```
myView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

[Existem 3 modos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOverScrollMode(int)):

- **OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS**
  modo padrão, o efeito é sempre visível.
- **OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS**
  o efeito só é visível quando o conteúdo da view é maior que as dimensões dela.
- **OVER_SCROLL_NEVER**
  o efeito nunca é visível.

Nota: O *scroll mode* só é aplicável a *views* capazes de ter o conteúdo deslocável.